# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server : FATAL: role "apache" does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, codeigniter-3, postgresql-9.4, php-7.3

Using PHP 7.3, Codeigniter 3.0.5, PostgreSQL 9
I am getting an error
`pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: role "apache" does not exist`

My application would create the db will automatically during a coded installation process. I had to do CI upgrade to the next higher version 3.0.6 and check the working of the installation process. So I have used the psql command to drop the existing db- `DROP DATABASE dbname;` using the postgres command line as a superuser -  `su - postgres`

I am getting the fatal error as given above when the db is dropped and testing the upgrade(NOTE:- The same testing process has been successful for the previous upgrade testing) . Anyone has any idea why this is occurring and any solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me something is trying to connect to the database using the Web server(Apache I presume) user name. The error is telling you there is no database role(user) by that name. Your options are to connect using a role that exists in the database or `CREATE ROLE apache` so it does exist in the database.